# Forward wifi traffic through tncattach adapter over LoRa

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi, ethernet, lora

I want to provide Internet access (IP traffic) over LoRa (I know about the airtime limitations). I have two RaspberryPis, with a LoRa hat. One has a WiFi access point (wlan0) the other one is connected to ethernet (eth0).

Hats are configured in point-to-point mode with `tncattach`:

```
sudo tncattach /dev/ttyS0 115200 -e -d --noipv6 --noup --mtu 236
ifconfig tnc0 10.0.0.1 pointopoint 10.0.0.2
and on the other one
ifconfig tnc0 10.0.0.2 pointopoint 10.0.0.1
```

Pings are possible.

Now on RaspberryPi1 I followed this [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point) routing the traffic of the WiFi (wlan0) to tncattach (tnc0).

My question now is, how do I bridge RaspberryPi2's tnc0 to eth0, to provide internet to RaspberryPi1?